# Mongoose aggregation of documents with similar values in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find the solution to a problem but don't get any further.

I have a number of documents in my collection, each containing an array with some values:

```
[{id:0,arr:[1,2,3,4]},{id:1,arr:[4,5,6,7]},{id:2,arr:[3,7,8]}]
```

I am trying to build an aggregation pipeline which would allow me to order the documents sorted by the similarity to a given array, such as:

```
var values = [1,3];
```

would result in:

```
[{id:0,arr:[1,2,3,4],similarity:2},{id:2,arr:[3,7,8],similarity:1}]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more digging and found a solution:

```
aggregate([
  {$match: {'arr':{$in:values}}},
  {$unwind: "$arr"},
  {$match: {'arr':{$in:values}}},
  {$group: {
    _id:'$_id', 
    matches: {"$sum": 1}
  }},
  {$sort: {matches:-1}},
  {$limit:limit}
], function(err, result) {
  ...
});
```

The trick was to add a second match, which would remove the irrelevant values in the array and do a simple count of the remaining values.